# Why is Facebook post batching failing with GraphBatchException - #0?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Here is the code I'm using to test batching using the C# Facebook SDK 6.8.0 from NuGet:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
client.AppId = application.FacebookAppId;
client.AppSecret = application.FacebookAppSecret;

var batchedRequests = new List<FacebookBatchParameter>();
batchedRequests.Add(new FacebookBatchParameter()
{
    HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
    Path = "2982XXXXXXXXXX001/feed",
    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"access_token", "CAAK9UGtbUaMBAKX..."},
        {"message", "Check out our stuff at Google: " + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks},
        {"link", "http://www.google.com"}
    }
});
batchedRequests.Add(new FacebookBatchParameter()
{
    HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
    Path = "755XXXXXXXXXX21/photos",
    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"access_token", "CAAK9UGtbUaMBAA6..."},
        {"message", "Lions, oh my! " + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks},
        {"url", "http://i.imgur.com/DVSsmpa.jpg"}
    }
});
batchedRequests.Add(new FacebookBatchParameter()
{
    HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
    Path = "2982XXXXXXXXXX001/feed", // Same as first
    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"access_token", "CAAK9UGtbUaMBAKX..."}, // Same as first
        {"message", "Check out our stuff at Facebook: " + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks},
        {"link", "http://www.facebook.com"}
    }
});

var batchedParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
batchedParams.Add("access_token", defaultPage.PageAccessToken);

dynamic facebookResponse = client.Batch(batchedRequests.ToArray(), batchedParams);
```

If I comment out any one of the three batchedRequests.Add() calls, it works fine.

It only breaks if all three are together.

Here's the error I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: Facebook.FacebookApiException: (GraphBatchException - #0) Batch parameter must be a JSON array
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(Object parameters)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Batch(FacebookBatchParameter[] batchParameters, Object parameters)
   at FacebookTest.Program.FacebookBatchTest() in c:\Test\Program.cs:line 81
   at FacebookTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Test\Program.cs:line 23
```

Comment: The error implies your batch isn't correctly encoded/wrapped/serialised - have you debugged that?

Comment: It works one or two records at a time, but having all 3 causes it fail.  I'm not sure what needs to be wrapped at this point.

Comment: I suspect it might be an issue with how the FacebookClient.Batch() method is handling the request, but unfortunately, I don't have any visibility into that to see what URL call is being passed to Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with C# Facebook SDK.  If the total request is longer than 999 characters, it fails to properly encode.

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/315